# Put in an array/session after getting value from a function

Tags: php, yii2

Hello I have a process where the user clicks an add button then it saves the information into the database then fetch it via another function. But what I want to do is to skip the database saving then just put it in an array or session (whatever is possible) then use it to put in a view. Is this possible?

Here is my current code:

Add button in the view:

```
    <p>
     <?= Html::a('<b>ADD</b>',
     ['site/addsubject', 'TrNo' => $subjects['TrNo'], 'clientid' => $_user],
     ['class' => 'btn-info btn-transparent btn-large', 'data-method' => 'post']) ?>
   </p>
```

Then the function in the controller:

```
 public function actionAddsubject($TrNo, $clientid){
      //echo $subjectid;
      //echo "Hello";
      $model = new ActiveSubject();
      //$var =  $model->AddSubject($subjectid);
      $model->AddSubject($TrNo, $clientid);
       $this->redirect(array('site/main'));

     // echo $var->subjectname;
     //echo $var['subjectname'];
    }
```

The model where it does the saving

```
public static function AddSubject($TrNo, $clientid){
  $subject = ActiveCurriculum::find()
                                ->select('scstock.*')
                                ->joinWith('schead')
                                ->where(['schead.TrNo' => $TrNo])
                                ->one();

    $activesubject = new ActiveSubject();
    $activesubject->clientid = $clientid;
    $activesubject->TrNo = $subject->TrNo;
    $activesubject->subjectcode = $subject->subjectcode;
    $activesubject->schedday = $subject->schedday;
    $activesubject->schedtime = $subject->schedtime;
    //remember to use schead if the value is joined from another table.
    $activesubject->section = $subject->schead->section;
    $activesubject->roomcode = $subject->roomcode;
    $activesubject->units = $subject->units;
    $activesubject->save();
//reduces the slot of ccsubject by 1
     $subject->slots = $subject->slots - 1;
     //never forget the saving part
     $subject->save();

        return true;

}
```

Is it possible to just store it in an array or session and make it accessible in the views? I imagine putting it in variable but how would I handle the add button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For temporary storage of data in a user session,you can do it like

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;

//check if session is active
if ($session->isActive)
{

     $session->set('subject', 'Maths');       

}
```

To retrieve the data that is stored in the session,you can do like

```
 $session = Yii::$app->session;

 if ($session->isActive)
 {

     $subject = $session->get('subject');    

 }
```

Use this link to learn more about session handling in yii2

http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/session-handling-in-yii-framework-2-0/

However if your purpose is just to store data temporarily, so that it is available in the next action or view, you can do it like

```
public function  actionAddsubject($TrNo, $clientid)
{

   //just showing an example of a variable that holds some data
   $subject = "Maths";

   //redirect to action site/main and make the $subject data available there
   return $this->redirect(['site/main', 'subject' => $subject ]);


}
```

Please note the above code will redirect to action site/main where the data $subject is made available.To access the data $subject in site/main, you can do it like

```
public function actionMain($subject)
{
    //now you can do whatever with $subject
}
```